# EF MappingApi returns column name for parent class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I'm building a generic method which must insert alot of data. So I'm using SqlBulkCopy for insertion, reflection to get values from objects and MappingApi to get DB schema. I don't need to insert nested objects in order to keep it as simple as possible.

I'm trying to get table name like this:

```
using (var ctx = GetStorage())
{
    tableName = ctx.Db(typeof(T)).TableName;
}
```

It's working for base classes but not for derived classes.

Schema:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class B: A
{
    public int Site_Id { get; set; }
}

public class AMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired();

        ToTable("A");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    }
}

public class BMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Site_Id).IsRequired();

        ToTable("B");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(t => t.Site_Id).HasColumnName("Site_Id");
    }
}
```

EF CRUD operations are working on this schema. EF is sending two requests per each operation first for class B and then for class A. But, `ctx.Db(typeof(B)).TableName == "A"`

Any ideas on how to get throw this and get right table name for class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use attribute instead ToTable("B"), here is a simple solution

```
public static string GetTableName<T>()
        {
            var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (T), typeof (TableAttribute)).OfType<TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (attr != null)
            {
                return attr.Name;
            }

            throw new Exception("Could not load TableAttribute of type" + typeof (T).Name);
        }
```